# solving 8-puzzle with BFS algorithm using Python

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, puzzle

I want to solve 8-puzzle problem with bfs algorithm and using Python
this is my code, I don't get what exactly is the problem with my code. But it keeps running and doesn't stop and does not solve the problem.

```
list = [1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5]
goal_list=[2,8,1,0,4,3,7,6,5]
for i in list:
    if list[i]==0:
        x=i
print(x)

count=0
check="false"
list_up=[]
list_down=[]
list_left=[]
list_right=[]
list_copy=[]
queue=[]
save_list=[]


up=x-3
down=x+3
left=x-1
right=x+1

if up>=0:

    list_up=list.copy()
    list_up[x]=list_up[up]
    list_up[up]=0
    u=up
    up=u-3
    count+=1
    queue.append(list_up)
    save_list.append(list_up)
    print (queue)
    if list_up==goal_list:
        #check=true
        print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)

if down<=8:
    list_down=list.copy()
    list_down[x]=list_down[down]
    list_down[down]=0
    count+=1
    d=down
    down=d+3
    queue.append(list_down)
    save_list.append(list_down)
    if list_down==goal_list:
        print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)

if left>=0:
    list_left=list.copy()
    list_left[x]=list_left[left]
    list_left[left]=0
    count+=1
    l=left
    left=l-1
    queue.append(list_left)
    save_list.append(list_left)
    if list_left==goal_list:
        print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)

if right<=8:
    list_right=list.copy()
    list_right[x]=list_right[right]
    list_right[right]=0
    count+=1
    r=right
    right=r+1
    queue.append(list_right)
    save_list.append(list_right)
    print("in if right")
    if list_right==goal_list:
        print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)
    #print(queue.pop(0))    


def go_up():
    global up
    global u
    global count
    global check
    global queue
    global list_up
    global save_list
    global goal_list
    print("in up def")
    for i in list_up:
        if list_up[i]==0:
            u=i
            up=u-3
    if up>=0:
        list_up[u]=list_up[up]
        list_up[up]=0
        count+=1
        #u=up
        #up=u-3
        queue.append(list_up)
        save_list.append(list_up)
        if list_up==goal_list:
            check="true"
            print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)
            print(save_list)


def go_down():
    global down
    global d
    global count
    global check
    global queue
    global list_down
    global save_list
    global goal_list
    for i in list_down:
        if list_down[i]==0:
            d=i
            down=d+3
    if down<=8:
        print("in down def")
        #list_down=list.copy()

        list_down[d]=list_down[down]
        list_down[down]=0
        count+=1
        d=down
        down=d+3
        queue.append(list_down)
        save_list.append(list_down)
        if list_down==goal_list:
            check="true"
            print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)
            print(save_list)


def go_left():
    global left
    global l
    global count
    global check
    global queue
    global list_left
    global save_list
    global goal_list
    for i in list_left:
        if list_left[i]==0:
            l=i
            left=l-1
    if left>=0:
       #if l not in[0,3,6] :
        if l==1|l==2|l==4|l==5|l==8|r==7:
           print("in left def")

           #list_left=list.copy()
           list_left[l]=list_left[left]
           list_left[left]=0
           count+=1
           l=left
           left=l-1
           queue.append(list_left)
           save_list.append(list_left)
           if list_left==goal_list:
               check="true"
               print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)
               print(save_list)


def go_right():
    global right
    global r
    global count
    global check
    global queue
    global list_right
    global save_list
    global goal_list
    for i in list_right:
        if list_right[i]==0:
            r=i
            right=r+1
    if right<=8:
        #if r not in[2,5,8]:
        if r==0|r==1|r==3|r==4|r==6|r==7:
            print("in right def")

            list_right[r]=list_right[right]
            list_right[right]=0
            count+=1
            r=right
            right=r+1
            queue.append(list_right)
            save_list.append(list_right)
            if list_right==goal_list:
                check="true"
                print("problem solved with %d tries" %count)
                print(save_list)



while check=="false":
    print("len queue is:")
    print(len(queue))
    if len(queue)>0:
        list_copy=queue.pop(0)
        print (len(queue))
        list_up=list_copy.copy()
        go_up();
        if check=="true":
            break


        list_down=list_copy.copy()
        go_down();
        if check=="true":
            break
        list_left=list_copy.copy()
        go_left();
        if check=="true":
            break
        list_right=list_copy.copy()
        go_right();
        if check=="true":
            break


print("out of while")
print (save_list)
print ()
```

I'm new to python ,any help would be appreciated

about my code:
list holds the initial state and goal_list is the final state. I set the check variable to check if the final goal is reached. x,u,d,l,r hold the index of 0 in list. save_list is the rout(way) code went through to reach final state.

once again thank you for your help

Comment: It might be a cultural thing, but I never heard of an 8 puzzle and what your data represents, so without explanation, I don't have the slightest idea of what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Tip: It would be more readable if your methods `go_up`, `go_down`, etc. had clear inputs and outputs (rather than relying on global variables).

Comment: I think what you are missing is that you keep putting lists in your `queue` without checking if you already explored those lists. Then you just keep checking the same lists indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but I can spot several problems right away.  There are statements like this:

```
if r==0|r==1|r==3|r==4|r==6|r==7
```

They don't work the way you seem to think they do.  Read up on logical operator chaining in Python.  For example, this expression actually evaluates False for r==1.

You were much closer with the statement you commented out:

```
#if r not in[2,5,8]:
```

That should be:

```
if r not in (2, 5, 8):
```

There must be a space after the in operator.

Do not use "list" as a variable name, since it is a built-in class in Python and its use can lead to subtle errors.  Also queue is not a good choice of variable name, since there are several standard library modules that use this name.

You should use global variables sparingly in any language.

Finally, I have a piece of friendly advice:  I think it's not a good idea to learn a new language by typing in 230 lines of complex code and then throwing up your hands when it doesn't work.  The chances that you can write that much bug-free code in a new language must be as close to zero as the chances that the sun will not come up tomorrow.  Start with a smaller problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...actually, with some edition the code worked and solved the puzzle right now. about your last advice, can you please tell me how can I learn a new programming language? for example python, what's the best way to really learn it?

Comment: I can tell you how I learned Python: First I found a very good book, "Python in a Nutshell" by Alex Martelli.  Unfortunately it's pretty old at this point, so you probably should try to find a newer one.  The first part of the book was a language overview, about 80 pages.  I read that more or less straight through.  The rest of the book dealt with Python's huge standard library, so I read that in small pieces.  I set myself simple problems and created some stupid little game, on my own time.  Then I picked a small task at work for my first professional project.  And on from there.

Comment: Thank you so much  @paul Cornelius